# Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document

Tags: magento2, admin, login

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document
Element 'resource', attribute 'id': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not accepted by the pattern '([A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){1,}_[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]{1,}::[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,}'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeId'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': Warning: No precomputed value available, the value was either invalid or something strange happend.
Line: 21

Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document
Element 'resource', attribute 'id': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not accepted by the pattern '([A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){1,}_[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]{1,}::[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,}'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeId'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': Warning: No precomputed value available, the value was either invalid or something strange happend.
Line: 21

#0 /vagrant/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()
#1 /vagrant/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(221): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()
#2 /vagrant/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(102): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()
#3 /vagrant/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(156): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->processLogin()
#4 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('admin', 'admin123')
#5 /vagrant/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(78): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', Array, Array)
#6 /vagrant/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('admin', 'admin123')
#7 /vagrant/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /vagrant/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#11 /vagrant/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /vagrant/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#14 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#18 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /vagrant/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#23 /vagrant/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#24 {main}

Comment: I'm also facing same problem, Plazathemes have many errors in xml

Answer (score 12):

In your **/`magento-root`/app/code/Plazathemes/Themeoptions/etc/acl.xml** file replace

```
<resource id="plazathemes_themeoptions::config" title="Themeoptions" />
```

with

```
<resource id="Plazathemes_Themeoptions::config" title="Themeoptions" />
```

Magento is looking for the `id` attribute with CamelCase value, which in your case seems not satisfying.

Comment: Most welcome NAGARAJU K !!

Comment: You are welcome!!

Answer (score 5):

You use CamleCase notation for id

> plazathemes_themeoptions::config -> PlazaThemes_ThemeOptions::config